# Idiomatic way of using multiple unpacks

Tags: python

I'd like to do multiple unpacks in a function call in Python ...

Let's say I have a function

```
def manhattan_dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)
```

What is the Pythonic way of calling it with "coordinates"? i.e assuming

```
coord1 = (0, 0)
coord2 = (0, 0)
```

I'd like to be able to call it like

```
manhattan_dist(*coord1, *coord2)
```

But this yields a syntax error (second asterix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator:

```
manhattan_dist(*(coord1 + coord2))
```

Note that `+` will work only if both items are of the same type, to support any iterable you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
manhattan_dist(*chain(coord1, coord2))
```